vehicle routing with time instants
I have $n$ vehicles. At every time instant $t$, I want to service a different set $S_t$ of customers whose locations are known. (for a start, assume $n = |S_t|$)
How do I find the optimal set of vehicle routes that minimize the total distance for vehicles, while maximizing the set of customers served?
Approach tried: at every instant, one can establish a bijection between vehicles and customers, and minimize the distance at that instant of time, using, say, the Hungarian algorithm for the assignment problem. But I am not sure this approach would give global optimum over all times. Would this be a good heuristic?

You said "minimize the total distance for vehicles, while maximizing the set of customers served", which suggests a bicriterion problem. Are you willing to leave some customers unserved in order to conserve mileage?

Hungarian method would need to know which customers you served at time t, and which ones you didn't. You can formulate this as a simple flow problem instead and solve optimally using minimum cost graph. You will need

A source node and each unit of flow coming out of it will be equal to vehicle leasing cost. One arc per customer (at all levels) will be connected from source node (thus, a vehicle can start at any time).
Connect each customer in level t to each customer in level t+1 indicating possible connections, and the cost being the travel cost.
Represent each customer as two nodes (arrival and departure) nodes. The arc connecting these will have a flow upper/lower bound of 1.
And a sink node at the end from all customers (indicating vehicle lease complete).

Once you have a solution, you can extract the vehicle routes by tracing and extracting flows from source to sink node.
